# Biased coin toss - developing standard deviation expression without use of any properties of special distributions

Tags: binomial-distribution

A coin that has a probability `p` of landing as `heads`.
I'm asked to develop an expression for the standard deviation to the number of times of the coins landing `heads` for a *single* coin toss as a function of `p`.
Without the use of any properties of special distributions, just from the general properties of a probability function and general definitions of the relevant terms.

I'm not sure of how to approach this *"without the use of any properties of special distributions"* as I'm guessing I cannot assume the problem has a binomial distribution model

Comment: I think the statement means "don't just write down the formula from the distribution, instead, work it out algebraically for yourself".

Comment: @jbowman Where would you say the starting point should be?

Comment: Write out the formula for variance: $E(x^2) - E^2(x)$, then calculate the two terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have your coin that lands on heads with probability $p$. This implies that in a perfect world if you toss it 100 times, p of the tosses will be heads.
Say that when you get heads the value of your coin is 1 and 0 otherwise

Now what would you expect to be your mean number of heads for n tosses?  It would be $np$. Indeed explicitly $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n x P(having \space \space head) = \sum_{i=1}^n p = np$

For the variance you do a simple extension: $Var(X) = E[(X-E[X])^2]$ Notice you already know $E[X]$